# QuickBlox Retrieve list of dialogs return error 422

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

I am trying to get list of dialoges after a user login.
here is my code

```
QBResponsePage *page = [QBResponsePage responsePageWithLimit:20];


[QBRequest dialogsForPage:page extendedRequest:nil successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, NSArray *dialogObjects, NSSet *dialogsUsersIDs, QBResponsePage *page) {

    NSLog(@"response = %@\n\n",response);
     NSLog(@"-------\ndialogObjects = %@",dialogObjects);

} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {

    NSLog(@"error is %@",response);

}];
```

it gives me error 422.
console log is

```
[QBCore] Response headers: {
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 45;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Wed, 28 Oct 2015 14:07:30 GMT";
"QB-Token-ExpirationDate" = "2015-10-28 16:07:30 UTC";
"QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
Server = "nginx/1.6.2";
Status = "422 Unprocessable Entity";
"X-Rack-Cache" = miss;
"X-Request-Id" = 560260a8bf98da9b7c3d8ba133c8d7a7;
"X-Runtime" = "0.007757";
"X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
```

Why is it giving me error, im using the code they have given in there DOCs

Answer (score 2):

Check error reasons error block. it gives you error in simple language.

```
errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
NSLog(@"ERROR GROUP %@",response.error.reasons);
}];
```